# ruby -v different from rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm

```
Mohameds-MacBook-Pro-2:~ mmahalwy$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.1.1 [ missing bin/ruby ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

Mohameds-MacBook-Pro-2:~ mmahalwy$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
```

I need to get the system to use the RVM ruby and not the preinstalled ruby that ships with Mavericks.

I do have the `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` at end of .bashrc file

I also get this error when i start a new terminal session:

```
bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you add  [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" to your .bashrc ?

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned what you have tried so far. The following commands typically works for me after install RVM.

Assuming you have installed rvm using this

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Then you just have to install ruby and mark it as default ruby for your system.

```
rvm install 2.1.1     
rvm use 2.1.1 --default
```

I have a Mac and I have done this many times and yet to face an issue.